# How do i update the content in my database?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update values I got from the database but it seems not to be going to the routes function

I tried changing the routes method and even die down the request but it seems not to work

Here is the route

```
Route::put("/users/bonus/update/{id}", 
       [
         "uses" => "AdminDashboardController@updatebonus",
         "as"=> "userbonus.mer"
       ]);
```

below is the function that is been called to update

```
public function updatebonus(Request $request, $id)
{

    if (auth()->user()->isAdmin != 1) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    } else if (auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1) {

        $bonus=OtherBonus::where('id','=','$id')->first();
        $bonus->card_bonus=trim(strip_tags($request['cbonus']));
        $bonus->monthly_bonus=trim(strip_tags($request['mbonus']));
        $bonus->travelling_bonus=trim(strip_tags($request['tbonus']));
        $bonus->festival_bonus=trim(strip_tags($request['fbonus']));
        $bonus->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Bonus Settings 
Successfully updated");
    }
}
```

below is the form that passes the data to the function which communicates with the database.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  action="{{route('userbonus.mer', ['id'=>$bonus['id']])}}" method="PUT">

                            <span class="section">General Bonus in %age</span>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="cbonus">Card
                                    Bonus <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                                           value="{{$bonus['card_bonus']}}" name="cbonus"
                                           placeholder="10.00%" required="required" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="fbonus">Festival
                                    Bonus<span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" name="fbonus" required="required"
                                           value="{{$bonus['festival_bonus']}}"
                                           class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="34.6%">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="mbons">Monthly
                                    Bonus <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="mbonus" required="required"
                                           value="{{$bonus['monthly_bonus']}}" placeholder="56.9%"
                                           class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="tbonus">Travelling
                                    Bonus <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="tbonus" placeholder="0.89%"
                                           value="{{$bonus['travelling_bonus']}}" required="required"
                                           class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML form doesn't accept `PUT` as method. It only works with `GET` and `POST`. Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method). So if you write

```html
<form method="PUT"></form>
```

you're going to submit the form as a `GET` request. Laravel listens for a specific input that has to present after form submission in order to recognize the `PUT` method. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```php
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

You may use the @method Blade directive to generate the _method input:

```php
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function updatebonus(Request $request, $id)
{

    if (auth()->user()->isAdmin != 1) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    } else if (auth()->user()->isAdmin == 1) {

        $bonus=OtherBonus::find($id);
        $bonus->update([
          'monthly_bonus'=>$request->mbonus,
           'travelling_bonus'=>$request->tbonus,
          'festival_bonus'->$request->fbonus;
]);


        return redirect()->back()->with("success", "Bonus Settings 
Successfully updated");
    }
}
```

And BLADE FILE JUST CHANGE METHOD TO post & and after this add  {{method_field('PUT')}}
                                {{csrf_field()}}

```
   <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  action="{{route('userbonus.mer', ['id'=>$bonus['id']])}}" method="post">
                             {{method_field('PUT')}}
                                {{csrf_field()}}

                            <span class="section">General Bonus in %age</span>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="cbonus">Card
                                    Bonus <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                                           value="{{$bonus['card_bonus']}}" name="cbonus"
                                           placeholder="10.00%" required="required" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="fbonus">Festival
                                    Bonus<span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" name="fbonus" required="required"
                                           value="{{$bonus['festival_bonus']}}"
                                           class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="34.6%">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="mbons">Monthly
                                    Bonus <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="mbonus" required="required"
                                           value="{{$bonus['monthly_bonus']}}" placeholder="56.9%"
                                           class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="tbonus">Travelling
                                    Bonus <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="tbonus" placeholder="0.89%"
                                           value="{{$bonus['travelling_bonus']}}" required="required"
                                           class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

In Route make it post